# Get a reference to the object that called a method?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a dll that includes:

```
public abstract class Module
{
   internal int ID;

   public abstract void ModuleStart();

}

public void function1() {}
public void function2() {}
//etc...
```

And then I have another dll that references the above dll and has:

```
class MyModule : Module
{
   public override void ModuleStart()
   {
      function1();

   }

}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is have function1 known the value of the calling module's ID, without it being passed in. Is there a way to do this? Basically what I'm trying to do is, the main Module DLL is loaded up, a method is run that loads in the second dll, uses reflection to make sure it has a child of Module, assigns it an ID and runs ModuleStart. MyModule can then do what it needs, calling functions from the first dll in order to access internal protected memory, but when the functions are called they need to know the ID of the Module that called them. Is this possible? MyModule has no knowledge of its ID, nor an ability to change it.

Comment: You could try crawling your application stack.  http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-callstack/

Comment: Why do you **need** to do this without it being passed in / available as a property on whichever object `function1` is a member of? Seems like the straightforward approach here.

Comment: @millimoose If I get you correct, this was the way it used to be done. The Module class had a reference to an object with all of these functions and that object also had the ID set. The thing is, the number of functions are growing heavily and I wanted to use namespaces to help order things better. Though I now realize I might be able to simulate this with static classes. The basic idea was to make this simple to use, like importing an API, even though it doesn't actually function that way behind the scenes.

Comment: @millimoose The idea is to make this easier to use for my other programmers. If they want to make their own module and drop it in, all they have to do is add a reference to the first dll, create a child to Module, and then call whatever methods they want from that library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.NET 4.5 adds some functionality to do something similar to this with the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx). Here's a sample from the docs:

```
public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}
```

Comment: Useful, though unfortunately I'm limited to 4.0

Answer (score 1):

A few people have suggested using the call stack to get the module information.  If you want to get the *type* of object that made the call, it's not too bad.  Unfortunately there is no feasible (ie: simple, portable and functional) method to extract *instance* information from data in the call stack.  There are several reasons why, including problems with optimization inlining methods that then do not show on the stack... which can interfere with calling *type* detection as well.

Given this fact, the short answer is that you have to provide a `Module` object as a parameter to the methods you are calling in the DLL.  The method suggested by @p.s.w.g is one way of achieving this, but has the disadvantage of potentially polluting the symbol space of the `Module` class.  This can be solved by having the `Module` class implement a protected or public API member that exposes the functions you want to provide:

```
public abstract class Module
{
    internal int ID;

    public class APIWrapper
    {
        Module module;

        public APIWrapper(Module module)
        {
            this.module = module;
        }

        public void method1() { apiimpl.method1(this.module); }
        public int method2() { return apiimpl.method2(this.module); }
    }

    public readonly APIWrapper API;

    public Module()
    {
        ID = generate_module_identity();
        API = new APIWrapper(this);
    }

    public abstract void ModuleStart();
}

internal static class apiimpl
{
    public static void method1(Module module) { ... }
    public static int method2(Module module) { ... }
}
```

The other developers can then use it this way:

```
class MyModule : Module
{
    public override void ModuleStart()
    {
        API.method1();
    }
}
```

This encapsulates the methods that your DLL exposes, without introducing too much pollution of the symbol space of the `Module` class hierarchy.

[opinion type="my" value="YMMV"]

However, I suggest that you seriously reconsider using this type of abstraction.  If the methods you are calling require some information about the specific `Module` instance that is calling them, it should be clear in the method's parameters.  Encouraging your team to follow guidelines that lead to clarity can be more important than finding ways to abstract away small details.

[/opinion]

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want is just to retrieve the `ID` at run-time, without passing any arguments into `function1`, you can use inherited methods:

```
public abstract class Module
{
    internal int ID;
    public abstract void ModuleStart();

    protected void function1()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine ("function1 called from module {0}", this.ID);
    }
}
```

Then, from your other modules, calling `function1` looks as simple as this:

```
class MyModule : Module
{
   public override void ModuleStart()
   {
      this.function1();    // the 'this.' is not required
   }
}
```

However, I get the sense from your comments that you want to make keep these functions separate from your `Module` class, since you are routinely adding new functions. You can do almost the exact same thing using [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx) to maintain the *appearance* of not passing any parameters:

```
public abstract class Module
{
   internal int ID;
   public abstract void ModuleStart();
}

public static class ModuleExtensions
{
   public static void function1(this Module module)
   {
       innerFunction1(module.ID);
   }

   internal static void innerFunction1(int ID)
   {
        System.Console.WriteLine ("function1 called from module {0}", ID);
   }
}
```

Then, from your other modules, calling `function1` looks as simple as this:

```
class MyModule : Module
{
   public override void ModuleStart()
   {
      this.function1();     // the 'this.' is required
   }
}
```